# Next regular expression construction does not work, why?

Tags: regex

I have the next command-line option which I need to split in a name-value format:

```
-table tab -delimiter "," -limit:10
```

The regexp construction is:

```
(?<=[-{1,2}|/])(?<name>[a-zA-Z0-9_]*)[ |:|"]*(?<value>[0-9A-Za-z.?=&\|+ :'*(),\\]*)(?=[ |"]|$)
```

My problem is in the delimiter option,  when I put `-delimiter "|"` or `-delimiter ":"`, the regexp construction doesn't work in spite I included these characters, in those cases: name=delimiter, but value is equal to empty, why?

Thanks for your help.

Edit:
Tim and Gabe, thanks for your help.
The final construction that works is:

```
(?<=-{1,2}|/)(?<name>[a-zA-Z0-9_]*)\s*:?\s*"? *(?<value>[0-9A-Za-z.?=&\|+ :'*(),\\]*)(?=[ "]|$)
```

Comment: You need to be clearer about what defines a name and what defines a value here. Is limit:10 the only name=value pair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in `[ |:|"]*` -- it appears as though you think `|` means "or" within brackets even though you clearly don't use it in the next set of brackets.

You just want `[ :"]*` probably, which would make `"|"` work. Unfortunately that group matches any number of characters that can be a space, colon, or quote, which means `":"` is all considered to be part of the space between the name and value. You will need to better define your allowed set of characters between the name and value.

I suggest: `\s*:?\s*"?` (any amount of space, followed by an optional colon, followed by any amount of space, followed by an optional quote).

Answer (score 2):

There are a few errors in your regex:

`[ |:|"]*` matches zero or more of these characters: space, `|`, `:` or `"`. You seem to be using this to identify possible separators between `name` and `value`.

Of course, in `-delimiter "|"` or `-delimiter ":"` it matches all the characters after `delimiter`, leaving nothing for the `value` part. Since that is optional, the regex matches successfully without filling the `value` part.

Another thing:

You probably don't want

```
(?<=[-{1,2}|/])
```

but rather

```
(?<=-{1,2}|/)
```

Looks like you should read up on [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

To fix your regex, we need to know the rules you're trying to implement. What exactly can separate a name/value pair?